# How do I turn off my Samsung Galaxy a3 if my screen has stopped working?

Tags: screen, touch

My phone screen suddenly just stopped working it comes on but the touch screen isn't responding. I think I need to switch it off and back on again but I can't without touching the screen! Does anybody know how to do it another way?

Answer (score 1):

Hold down the power button for 10 seconds or take out battery

Comment: Galaxy A3  have a non-removable battery (check GSMArena) so "*take out battery*" isn't an option here.